# Closing a Channel, like in Go

Tags: rust, channel

Does Rust have a way of "closing" a channel, [similar to what is available in Go](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Close)?

The idea is to iterate over the channel (receive continually) until the channel indicates that it will not produce any more values.

```
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex};
use std::thread;
use std::sync::mpsc;

fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new(Mutex::new(0u32));
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel::<u32>();
    {
        let (data, tx) = (data.clone(), tx.clone());
        thread::spawn(move || {
            for _ in 0..10 {
                let mut data = data.lock().unwrap();
                *data += 1;
                tx.send(*data).unwrap();
            }
            // *** How could I close the channel here, to signal the work is done?
        });
    }

    // *** How can I detect a closed channel here? Pattern matching?
    for _ in 0..10 {
        let x = rx.recv().unwrap();
        println!("{}", x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have any code that represents what you're trying to do?

Comment: @tadman [A rather silly] Example added

Comment: the docs already answer this imo: https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/sync/mpsc/struct.Sender.html#method.send Dropping the `tx` (as it happens after the for loop since the scope ends) will cause the `rx` to return an `Err` instead of an `Ok` on the next `recv`. Then you can pattern match on the result of `recv` to check for `Ok` or `Err`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The channel is closed when all Senders have dropped. In your code you clone and give one each to each thread, these drop as they should when the threads end. The last sender is in the main thread, and you should drop it as soon as all the threads have been spawned: `drop(tx)`.

Finally, the easiest way to receive is this, *after* the `drop(tx)`.

```
for elt in rx {
    /* */
}
```

This loop ends when the channel is closed.

Comment: Exactly what I needed! Here is a simplified working example on the playground: http://is.gd/jfSQD2

Comment: That's cool but an incredibly wasteful way to iterate (it's an OS thread too), so I haven't seen that much in Rust.

Comment: It's definitely wasteful in this case - just an example. Depending on the resource inside the thread, it could be different?